# How to init a value in a class with a simple setting and getting attributes?

Tags: python, class

The class I have been using looks simple, like this:

```
class Transaction(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

and then sending in:

```
transaction = Transaction({"to": "0x000", "from": "0x001": "timestamp": 1234})
```

and of course can be used like this `transaction.to`, however it looks like `transaction.from` does not work because `from` is a python reserved keyword

So I am curious using that simple class, is there a way to reassign `from` in the class to be something like

```
self.sender = dict.from
```

I have been trying with `__init__` but with no luck

I also have written the class just with an `__init__` and then assigning all values using `self` but with out a getter the class is not iterable

What I have been doing looks like this

```
# given data - {"to": "0x000", "from": "0x001": "timestamp": 1234}
item["sender"] = item["from"]
transaction = Transaction(item)
```

and then I have reference to it like `transaction.sender`.

Comment: "because from is a python reserved keyword?": yes. You'll get a SyntaxError.

Comment: "Reserved" means you can't reassign it. If you could, Python's grammar wouldn't work.

Comment: " is there a way to reassign from in the class [...]": no, because there is no `from` in a class or instance. There is no `dict.from`.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but `__getattr__ = dict.get` is probably a bad idea. Attribute lookups will never fail since `dict.get` always returns a value. Use `dict.__getitem__` instead.

Comment: You shouldn't try to make a dict into a class. Don't fight the syntax. A dict uses `mydict[key]`, not `mydict.key` in Python. That is clear for everyone; don't try and change it.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider dataclasses, or if you don't need the setter part (or only to initialise the object), consider named tuples.

Comment: Could you please [edit] and turn the title into a question? The body of your post asks two different questions (if `from` is a keyword and if there's a way to use a different attribute name). Clarifying the title would clarify your end goal.

Comment: @wjandrea I think the OP wants dot-assignment (or whatever one likes to call it) for something like a dict. Judging from the various `transaction.to/from` etc mentions, and the whole reassignment of `__setattr__` to `__setitem__` etc. See also a comment of mine above.

Comment: Why does the class need to be iterable?

Comment: @wjandrea maybe I am going about this the wrong way, later in the code in an if block - looks like this

if (
    "sender" in transaction
   ...
):

Comment: @Chipe Ohh, yeah, try this instead, `try: transaction.sender; except AttributeError: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your end goal is to have a class that can be instantiated from a dict and expose the keys as attributes. I'm inferring that the dict can only contain certain keys since you're talking about mapping `"from"` to `sender`. In that case, I would do this completely differently: don't subclass `dict`, instead have an alternate constructor that can handle the dict. I'd keep a "normal" constructor mostly for the sake of the repr.

For example:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, to, from_, timestamp):
        self.to = to
        self.from_ = from_
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return cls(d['to'], d['from'], d['timestamp'])

    def __repr__(self):
        """Show construction."""
        r = '{}({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(
            type(self).__name__,
            self.to,
            self.from_,
            self.timestamp)
        return r

transaction = Transaction.from_dict({"to": "0x000", "from": "0x001", "timestamp": 1234})
print(transaction)  # -> Transaction('0x000', '0x001', 1234)
print(transaction.from_)  # -> 0x001
```

Here I'm using the trailing underscore convention [covered in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   ```
>   tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
>   ```

---

By the way, if it's useful, the [`keyword` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) contains the names of all Python keywords.